# Create repeating pattern of raster or polygons in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon-creation, simulation

I want to create a repeating pattern of raster OR polygon features based on an existing sample, so that the sample fills up a larger area in a repeating pattern. For example, with a sample of 10x10 units I want to fill an area of 100x100 units with 100 samples.

[image: The sample area is to fill a given area, used as a mask later]

The goal is to create a mask of repeating pattern, similating a specific landscape type or pattern. This mask is then to be clipped by polygons to fit in a map, used for landscape change and connectivity analysis.

I have browsed around existing tools, but the only way I have found so far is to manually copy+paste the feature x times, risking both inconsistency and topological errors.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in ArcGIS for Desktop or QGIS the most?  So that you are asking a single focussed question (not one for each of two products) please choose one or the other to prevent your question being too broad.

Comment: I suspect this is an example of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  There are many potential ways to construct fill patterns that do not require this solution.  You might get a better answer if you ask about the problem, not your proposed solution.

Comment: Ok. Specified to ArcGIS in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Vince, regarding the XY problem. I do not know how to start solving the problem and are happy for any suggestions. I have tried to specify the problem and the broader picture in which it is to be used. Thank you.

Comment: That's not how things work here. We need a focused, well-described problem statement so that a solution can be generated.

Comment: Thank you Vince. I will search for help and suggestions elsewhere then. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I think you just need to use a picture fill symbol with the picture being your sample area.  Perhaps experiment with that option on the Symbol Selector.

Comment: @ PolyGeo. I don't think this is about symbology, but about actual data generation and consequent extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the the original raster image and replicate it in a image processing tool like [gimp (see instructions under this link)](https://superuser.com/questions/384393/using-gimp-easiest-way-to-repeat-an-image-in-a-tiled-fashion) 
Afterwards you adjust the header information of the new raster image multiplying the extent by the amount of replicates.

However, I am sure this would also by possible in ArcPy.